# Что делать если на странице при вёрстке остаётся много пустого места

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial MT";
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

header {
  min-width: 1280px;
  min-height: 323px;
  background: #445162;
}

#Headline1 {
  width: 367px;
  height: 44px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.Headline {
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

.list1 li {
  width: 422px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 25px;
}

.icon {
  list-style-image: url(check_icon.png);
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.white {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
  width: 469px;
  height: 214px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: -195px 640px 0px 0px;
}

.block1 {
  min-width: 280px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#About1 {
  width: 254px;
  height: 28px;
  color: #445161;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

#text1 {
  width: 649px;
  height: 63px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

#text2 {
  width: 653px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Arial MT";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
  width: 430px;
  height: 245px;
  background-color: #445162;
  margin: -175px 673px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="Headline">
    <h1 id="Headline1">Product name</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="list1">
      <br>
      <br>
      <li class="icon">Put on this page information about your product</li>
      <li class="icon">A detailed description of your product</li>
      <li class="icon">Tell us about the advantages and merits</li>
      <li class="icon">Associate the page with the payment system</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="white"></div>
</header>
<!-- block1 -->
<div class="block1">
  <div class="About"></div>
  <div id="About1">About your product</div>
  <br>
  <p id="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis facilis fuga, illo at. Natus eos, eligendi illum rerum omnis porro ex, magni, explicabo veniam incidunt in quam sapiente ut ipsum.</p>
  <p id="text2">Pariatur iure ab sunt nesciunt, quibusdam odio iste cumque itaque, ipsa vel exercitationem ullam quos aut nostrum cupiditate fuga quaerat quam animi dolores. Sequi itaque, unde perferendis nemo debitis dolor.</p>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

В Avocode вот так

[image: И должно выглядеть вот так]

А по итогу получается много пустого места, как это исправить ? ``[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи верстку, тут гадалок и ясновидящих нет. Вопрос должен содержать минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример. Описание проблемы и желаемый окончательный результат...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Вот код https://codepen.io/Dezzer/pen/BvRvPv

Comment: @Dezzer ваш код невалидный https://validator.w3.org

Comment: и добавьте его в в ваш вопрос

Comment: К чему эти правила `margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;` прописаны для чуть ли не для всех тегов?

Comment: Я просто вставил Reset CSS и там были эти правила

Comment: как минимум разные шрифты и его размеры, плюс макет для ширины 1280, а на какой ширине проверял ты - неизвестно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ограничить сам блок то всё будет как положено

И меньше проблем потом будет с адаптацией

[Вот так](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MZowgK?editors=1100) это будет на весь экран

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #445162;
  color: #fff;
}

.items:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.items:nth-of-type(2) p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <li><i>✓</i><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></li>
      <li><i>✓</i><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aut,</span></li>
      <li><i>✓</i><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></li>
      <li><i>✓</i><span>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x140/fff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam accusamus quidem cumque sit quod commodi omnis inventore ab eaque placeat!</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam accusamus quidem cumque sit quod commodi omnis inventore ab eaque placeat!</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam accusamus quidem cumque sit quod commodi omnis inventore ab eaque placeat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x140/445162" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить контейнер-центровщик, чтобы контент был по центру окна браузера. [codepen](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/full/BvRxbE)

```css
.block--blue {
  background: blue;
}

.block--gray {
  background: gray;
}

.block__wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section class="block block--blue">
    <div class="block__wrapper">
        Контент первого блока
    </div>
</section>

<section class="block block--gray">
    <div class="block__wrapper">
        Контент второго блока
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Air, вполне себе отвечает на поставленный вопрос. Только вот, да, автор неправильно с точки зрения правил описывает свою задачу.

Comment: "Что делать если на странице при вёрстке остаётся много пустого места?" - добавить контейнеры, в примере я это и продемонстрировал. Все

Comment: @Air гадалок и ясновидящих здесь уже целых двое, я тоже сразу про центровщик подумал

Comment: Можно буду третьей гадалкой? :-) Так же подумал сразу о том же ^_^

Comment: Ворвусь тоже. Можно рекламными баннерами все пустое место залепить! Ненуачо? Главное чтоб поярче были

Comment: @Air Да собственно какой вопрос, такие и ответы и комментарии =)

Comment: Вот код https://codepen.io/Dezzer/pen/BvRvPv

Answer (score 0):

1. ВАРИАНТ! Сделать вёрстку полностью фиксированной. Т.е. главному эл-ту BODY (или main) - задать фиксированный размер по ширине макета width: *px.
2. ВАРИАНТ! Сделать вёрстку полностью резиновой. Т.е. Задать эл-ту BODY размер в 100%, потом для каждого блочка - задавать размеры в % - надо высчитывать... Резиновая вёрстка учиться в последний момент, после адаптива и смысла не имеет, а времени и трудов жрёт за троих...!!!
3. ВАРИАНТ! Центровка! Уже двое написали с хорошими примерами. Но это обычный фиксированный размер!